# How to bind JSON value to Activity Suggested action in Bot composer lg

Tags: botframework, adaptive-cards, bot-framework-composer

I have to add a dynamic suggestion for suggested action based on the API response
for example

```
[Activity
Text = You can filter the results with below options
SuggestedActions = Name | Status | Group | Id
]
```

[image]

instead of hard coding suggested action is it possible to bind data to josn response from API

[image: data: {}]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53213139/dynamic-prompt-choices-in-bot-framework-v4-node-js

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Adaptive Expressions to do a logic and if else loop to generate the suggested action.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-concept-adaptive-expressions?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=arithmetic#language-generation

```
[Activity
Text = You can filter the results with below options
SuggestedActions = SuggestedActionGenerated(apiResponse)
]


# SuggestedActionGenerated(apiResponse)
- ${apiResponse.name}| ${apiResponse.Status }| ${apiResponse.Group }| ${apiResponse.Id}}
```